# Run python 2 API in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to make an integration with a API whose documentation seems to be in python 2, but for several reasons I need to make the API request in python 3. As far as I know, `urllib2` does not exist in python 3, and I don't know how to address this

This is a mock API request to generate a token:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

values = """
  {
    "username": "usuario@api.com",
    "access_key": "NWNmMTczNGYtZjQ0OS00MjgwLTg51WItYjNiNWRiNGUxMjIzOnM/WDkqPypfVFN="
  }
"""

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Partner-Id': '[nombre de la aplicación que estás integrando]'
}
request = Request('https://private-anon-897d0a33f9-siigoapi.apiary-mock.com/auth', data=values, headers=headers)

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

Comment: There is documentation ( https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes ) and the `2to3` tool as starting points.

Comment: If you are just interacting with an API endpoint, why would the Python version matter?

Comment: @InSync, as far as I understand, OP has some documentation for the API, with examples written in python 2 and he has difficulty to translate the examples for his needs.

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2` is just `urllib` now. `Request` and `urlopen` are in `urllib.request` package.

Also, `print` is a regular function in python3, needing parenthesis, as any functions. And post data should be bytes, preferably urlencoded (instead of encoding them yourself, like you did).

```py
# It would probably be better to import urllib.request and urllib.parse
# But well, I try to keep it as close as the original
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode

# I keep value as dict, instead of making it a string. Making it a string is `urlencode` job
values = {
    "username": "usuario@api.com",
    "access_key": "NWNmMTczNGYtZjQ0OS00MjgwLTg51WItYjNiNWRiNGUxMjIzOnM/WDkqPypfVFN="
  }

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Partner-Id': '[nombre de la aplicación que estás integrando]'
}
# urlencode(values) does the job of creating the 
# string. And since data should be bytes, `.encode()` 
# transform that string into a bytes array
request = Request('https://private-anon-897d0a33f9-siigoapi.apiary-mock.com/auth', data=urlencode(values).encode(), headers=headers)

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
# print is a function
print(response_body)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it does work with the mock server. However when I change to the real URL (https://api.siigo.com/auth) and put my real user and key, I get a "bad request" error, and when using python 2.7 everything works as intended.

I've tested, and the mock server will take ANY dictionary as "values" and still work... Do you have any idea of hat might be going on? Maybe the format of the "values" dictionary is not correct?